# Single day view in google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Currently I know there are ways to insert the google calendar(the month view) into a google site with a script but is there a way to insert a view that displays only one day or a week?

Thanks,

Loren

Comment: Hi, have you taken a shot at creating your own 1 day view to embed?

Comment: @BryanP have you seen any examples on how to go about this?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible in Sites to manually insert a Calendar view that defaults to Week or Agenda views. You can do this by:

1. Going the Sites page you want to include the calendar in and selecting 'Edit page'
2. Select Insert > Calendar
3. Select the calendar(s) you want display (or paste in their web addresses) and clicking 'Select'
4. Selecting Week, Agenda or Month in the View select box, making any other option selections and then clicking 'Save'
5. Adjusting the positioning of the calendar in the page and then clicking 'Save'

It is also possible to [use Apps Script to write a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that displays calendar information, and [embed the web app into Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_your_web_app_in_google_sites). This would allow you to create a customized display of calendar or other information, if you desired.

There isn't currently a way to add gadgets or web apps to a Site programmatically with Apps Script -- that has to be done manually.